# How To Extract Pattern from a folder path (VBA Excel)

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, path, string

I'm pretty new to vba excel and trying to reorganise a very large file structure. Basically, all our equipment has a tag in the form of [A-Z][0-9]0-9][0-9][A-Z] e.g. J452G being a compressor. Every equipment has a folder with its name on (e.g. "C:\Users\Ron\Documents\J452G" consist of drawings, subfolders, excels, pdfs,..). The problem is that I would like to copy this equipment folders to a new directory such that all equipment tags have a folder within one single directory (to make alphabetical searching easy). Now these folders are distributed in a tree-like folder structure with lots of subfolders.

What I would like to do is

1. Extract the file paths (e.g. "C:\Users\Ron\Documents\J452G") 'This I already managed to do
2. Look for the pattern [A-Z][0-9]0-9][0-9][A-Z] and copy all files and subfolders to a new directory with the name of the equipment.

Result should be a main folder (e.g. C:\Users\Ron\Documents) containing a folder for every equipment tag with the corresponding documents enclosed.

I'm particularly stuck on how to extract the pattern [A-Z][0-9]0-9][0-9][A-Z] from a string if found and assigning is to the Destination:=

e.g. C:\Users\Ron\Documents\Nieuwe map \iets\Drogers\F941E\
copy content and subfolders to C:\Users\Ron\Documents\F941E\

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

VBA is too slow handling files, I think python would be a better choice for this one.
Here is a sample code you could use:

```
import os, re, shutil

rootDir = raw_input("Please enter the search directory: ") #use forward slashes
destDir= raw_input("Please enter the destination directory: ")
directoryList = []

for fold,subFold, f in os.walk(rootDir):
    match = re.search(r'.*[A-Z]\d\d\d[A-Z]', fold) #your pattern
    if match:
        directoryList.append(match.group()) #adds to a list of paths

directoryList = set(directoryList) #eliminate duplicates

for dir in directoryList: 
    #takes the last part as the folder name
    folderName = dir.split('/')[-1] 
    pasteDir = destDir+folderName
    shutil.copytree(dir, pasteDir) #creates the new folder and save files and subfldrs
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out VBA can handle regular expressions. Cool.
[Someone asked how in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops). That should handle any pattern-matching needs you have. It even has a pretty good explanation of how to use regular expressions if you're unfamiliar.

If you want to search just the current folder / file name for that pattern, here's a snippet to cut a full path down to just the last bit (be it a folder or file):

```
'Setup. This is probably not necessary for your already established code
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
fPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Documents\Nieuwe map \iets\Drogers\F941E\"

'Remove any trailing slashes
Do Until Right(fPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator
    fPath = Left(fPath, Len(fPath) - 1)
Loop

'Extract the last entry
fName = Mid(fPath, InStrRev(fPath, Application.PathSeparator) + 1)

'Print the result (again, probably not necessary for your application)
Debug.Print fName
```